# Why is my map from google maps api not being displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I am trying to display the map from the google maps api.

This is my geocode_metabox.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
    
    execute_js();


    function execute_js(){
            console.log("Hola Mundo");
    }

    function displayMap(){
        console.log("Display Map");
        var point = { lat: -34.5956145, lng: -58.4431949 };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('sf_geocode_map'),{
            zoom: 10,
            center: point
        });
    }
});
```

And this is my sf_geocode_metabox.php:

```
<?php

function sf_add_metabox_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style('sf_geocode_styles', CHILD_THEME_ASTRA_2020_URI . 'assets/css/geocode_metabox.css' );
    
    }
    
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sf_add_metabox_styles' ); 

function sf_add_metabox_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('sf_geocode_scripts', CHILD_THEME_ASTRA_2020_URI . 'assets/js/geocode_metabox.js' );
    
    }
    
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sf_add_metabox_scripts' ); 

function sf_google_maps_API() {
    wp_enqueue_script('googlemaps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&key=MYKEY&callback=displayMap');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sf_google_maps_API');


/*CREATE METABOX FOR GEOCODE*/    
function sf_geocode_metabox() {

add_meta_box(

'sf_geocode_metabox',

'Geocode Locator',

'sf_display_geocode_metabox',

'park',

'normal',

'high'

);

}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'sf_geocode_metabox' );

/*DISPLAY METABOX FIELDS*/

function sf_display_geocode_metabox(){

    $html = '<div class="sf_form_group">';
    
    $html .= '<label for="sf_address">Address</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" id="sf_address" name="sf_address" value="" placeholder="Insert an Address" />';

    $html .= '</div>';

    $html .= '<div class="sf_lat_long">';
    $html .= '<div class="sf_form_group">';
    $html .= '<label for="sf_latitude">Latitude</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" id="sf_latitude" name="sf_latitude" value="" placeholder="Insert a Latitude" />';
    $html .= '</div>';

    $html .= '<div class="sf_form_group">';
    $html .= '<label for="sf_longitude">Longitude</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" id="sf_longitude" name="sf_longitude" value="" placeholder="Insert a Longitude" />';
    $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= '</div>';

    $html .= '<div class="sf_form_group">';
    $html .= '<label for="sf_geocode_map">Map</label>';
    $html .= '<div id="sf_geocode_map" name="sf_geocode_map"></div>';
    $html .= '</div>';

    echo html_entity_decode($html);

}
```

For some reasons my callback function is not being triggered and my map is not being displayed.
The first function from my js file with the console.log is being triggered, so it is an issue on the function that sends some coordinates and generates the map.

Comment: I have no idea about Wordpress but within the `sf_google_maps_API` your script references the Javascript function `displayMap` - that function however is itself declared within the scope of `jQuery(document).ready(function ($){....}` so is probably(?)  not accessible when called in the script uri. To my mind that jQuery function is unnecessary

Comment: I do not see where `displayMap()` is executed in your code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Twisty it is being called as a callback in the api url...

Comment: @tukitooo1998 I do not see it, please clarify where you believe it's being called.

Comment: You should use `admin_enqueue_scripts` instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Comment: Move the displayMap function out of the document ready. It has nothing to do there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `admin_enqueue_scripts` instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

`wp_enqueue_scripts` is used for frontend users.

`admin_enqueue_scripts` is used for admin panel usage.